# Java PDF Creation

Tags: java, pdf

Does anyone have a free or open source library to recommend for the creation of PDF files in Java?  I know that iText is popular, but it is not free for commercial use.
A library for creating MS Word (.doc) files would also be helpful.

Comment: Which part of itext licensing says it cannot be used in commercial tool? http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php

Comment: From the link you included above:  
"You can be released from the requirements of the license by purchasing a commercial license. Buying such a license is mandatory as soon as you develop commercial activities involving the iText software without disclosing the source code of your own applications. These activities include: offering paid services to customers as an ASP, serving PDFs on the fly in a web application, shipping iText with a closed source product."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/210029/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) works well for creating MS Office documents programmatically. PDFBox, as already mentioned, works well for PDF creation.

Comment: I'm really looking for a recommendation based on experience. There are lots of libraries, but many are poorly documented or seem overly complex.  Do you have experience with Apache POI or PDFBox?

Comment: I've used POI to create MS Excel documents before. Once you understand how they're representing the data model, it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

[PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) allows you to create pdf files from a text file.

Comment: My experience with PDFBox was pretty negative.  Large files with foreign characters frequently threw OOM's.  That was approximately 3 years ago (version ~.7)

Comment: I only need English right now.  Is there word wrap functionality built into PDFBox?

Answer (score 1):

ps2pdf is a good unix utility for converting postscript files in to PDFs, and postscript in java is as easy as string manipulation.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm

Comment: I guess I could combine that with something like
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/commons/postscript.html if I didn't want to write postscript directly.

Answer (score 1):

A have experimeted with a number of options, the best one was [docx4j](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j)

Comment: Library recommendations meanwhile have become off topic on stack overflow (there now are other stack exchange sites for that). Thus, please do not add new recommendation answers.