# How to generate PDF from form data (Spring)

Tags: spring, pdf

I'm writing a request for help, I want to make a simple web app that will have some form of contact details, after all the data entered by the user after clicking Submit I would like to generate a simple PDF with this data + preview the PDF in the browser.

Can I help someone with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java PDF Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537046/java-pdf-creation)

Answer (score 0):

For generate PDF you can use **jasper-reports** or **MS WORD doc file + Apache POI**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/index.htm

Comment: Please add some more details on how will one use the tools you've mentioned to achieve what he wants. Simply linking libraries like this isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: While I also would prefer answers with more content, the question is not really precise enough to allow for clearly appropriate details.